# Добавление в домен две созданные виртуальные машины в VirtualBOX

Tags: администрирование, windows-7, virtualbox, windows-server-2012, виртуализация

У меня в VirtualBOX создана виртуальная машина с win server 2012. По заданию нужно было создать две последующие с win 7 с названием CLIENT01_FIO_gruppa и CLIENT02_FIO_gruppa и внести созданные эти виртуальные машины в домен, подскажите пожалуйста как внести их в домен? Целый день ищу решение на этот вопрос.

Comment: Семёрки видят тачку с 2012?

Comment: Конечно, я семерки настроил, в AD все сделал. Мне теперь две машины в Server  2012 внести или как?

Comment: Ну да. В 7 указать имя домена и ввести учёку пользователя у которого есть право вводить в домен.